# Retrieving dictionary<string, Action>

Tags: c#, dictionary, action

I'm building a parser for a text-based game, well trying is more like it. So I want to store all the possible verbs and nouns into their own dictionary. But I got an error when trying to retrieve the string key from the dictionary...

In my Dictionary class, I create the Verbs dictionary, like so:

```
public Dictionary<string, Action> Verbs = new Dictionary<string, Action>();
```

I then proceed to add some value to it:

```
public void PopulateVerbs()
    {
        Verbs.Add("MOVE", Action.MoveAction);          
    }
```

In my VerbAction class, I have methods that do stuff based on input:

```
Action Move = dictionary.Verbs["MOVE"];

    public void MoveAction()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You moved...");
    }
```

And finally, in my CommandHandler class, I handle the input:

```
if (InputToken[0] == dictionary.Verbs["MOVE"])
            Action.MoveAction();
```

And this is where I get the error, it says that the ["MOVE"] string that I'm trying to retrieve is in fact an action, so I'm a little confused. What am I missing here?

Comment: So basically what you have (the result ) is of type `Action`. meaning `Verbs["string"]= Action the_action_you_defined`. when you define `Dictionory<TKey,TValue> someDictionary=new Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` `someDictionary[TKey]` returns of type `TValue`

Comment: Yeah makes sense now, thanks for clearing that up!

Comment: It's not clear whether `Action` in this code is a custom `enum` or the built-in `delegate`. The second code snippet indicates the former. The final code snippet indicates the latter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Verbs["MOVE"] will get the *value* stored with the *key* "MOVE", so it will return an Action in this case.  I assume InputToken is a list of strings, and given that you have a dictionary full of string/action values representing your actions I might try something like this so you don't need a bunch of if checks:

Take

```
if (InputToken[0] == dictionary.Verbs["MOVE"])
        Action.MoveAction();
```

And use the dictionary to your advantage:

```
Action theAction = dictionary.Verbs[InputToken[0]];
theAction();
```

You can condense this further too:

```
dictionary.Verbs[InputToken[0]]();
```

Furthermore, the dictionary is a pretty robust class so you can use its features to start adding error handling checks (if Verbs.ContainsKey, etc)

Comment: Robust you say?! Thank you so much!

Comment: yes, you have to keep in mind that you could possibly demand a value for a non-existant key. The dictionary allows you to check beforehand